# Appending User Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, appendto

Situation:

I currently have a search box that utilizes Jquery’s Autocomplete plugin. When a user begins typing in the search box for a sport’s team (i.e. Boston Red Sox) it will determine relevant matches. When they select on the team I would like it to append to a list (perhaps it should be append to an array as this seems most common – but if it is an array I may need to alter my current content) so that they can have their sport’s team displayed on a navbar (my css allows for this currently) To get a better idea of what I am discussing here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/saLbjdw1/1/

Existing Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>TEST</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
     <style type="text/css">

</head>
```

I will skip the css portion unless requested (found in JSFiddle)

```
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="topbar">

            <div class="fixedwidth">

            <p><a href="">HOME</a></p>

            <ul>
                <li id="teamBRS" class="red"><a>BOSTON RED SOX</a></li>
                <li id="teamNEP" class="blue"><a>NEW ENGLAND PATRIOTS</a></li>
                <li id="teamBC" class="green"><a>BOSTON CELTICS</a></li>
                <li id="teamBB" class="gold" style=border-right:none;><a>BOSTON BRUINS</a></li>
            </ul>

                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <input id="tags" type="text" placeholder="Search Teams">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        </div>

        <script>

            $(function() {
                var availableTeams = [
                    "Boston Red Sox",
                    "New England Patriots",
                    "Boston Celtics",
                    "Boston Bruins",
                    "NEW ENGLAND REVOLUTION"
                ];
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableTeams
                });
            });

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I did attempt to piece together some of my thoughts on where I might begin after reviewing other stack posts such as; using JavaScript to append the user input (which was from the availableTeams [])to a new array called activeArray or list. After it is appended it would appear on the #topBar...hopefully

myThoughts:

```
    activeArray=["BOSTON RED SOX", "NEW ENGLAND PATRIOTS"];

        document.getElementById("tags").onClick=function() {

            if (document.getElementById("tags").value=="NEW ENGLAND REVOLUTION") {
                push searchedItem to activeArray
            }
            else {
                dont do anything
            }

            }
```

I realize a lot of what is shown just above is rubbish but I am in a very basic sense trying to outline some rough thoughts. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: so to simplified your question, do you mean you want to check if use import exist in current dataset if not add to data set?

Comment: So create an li and append the item to the UL.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/saLbjdw1/2/ such as this?

Comment: Wlin your example is great. I will just need to figure out a couple of things going forward; 1) Instead of submitting the exact value that is clicked I will need to figure out how I can push an answer associated with what is clicked - meaning, when I click Boston Red Sox, I will need a list item to be populated that has css formatting associated with it (all predetermined), 2)  instead of utilizing a button to submit I am going to try and have it when the user clicks on the team it populates the list item.